# перезапись файлов в многомерной таблице

Tags: php

На странице есть N полей с описанием и загрузкой файлов ( количество зависит от количества заданных языков)

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($mass_lg);$i++){ // $mass_lg - массив из языков
                if ($_POST['change_'.$mass_lg[$i].''] !=="" ){ // $_POST['change_'.$mass_lg[$i].''] поле ввода описания 
                    $mass = array('translate' => $_POST['change_'.$mass_lg[$i].'']);
                    $db->update('slider_main_translate', $mass, array('id_slide' => $_GET['id'],'langs' => $mass_lg[$i]));
                };                

                if ($_FILES['img_'.$mass_lg[$i].''] !== "") {  // $_FILES['img_'.$mass_lg[$i].''] сами файлы

                    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].IMAGE.'presentation/'.$mass_lg[$i]."_".$img_name[2]['image'])){
                        unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].IMAGE.'presentation/'.$mass_lg[$i]."_".$img_name[2]['image']);
                        $exmpl = new WorkWithFiles(); // новый экземпляр класса загрузки 
                        $exmpl->uploadFiles($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].IMAGE.'presentation/', $_FILES['img_'.$mass_lg[$i].''], $mass_lg[$i]."_".$img_name[2]['image']);  // метод для загрузки
                    } else {
                        $exmpl = new WorkWithFiles();
                        $exmpl->uploadFiles($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].IMAGE.'presentation/', $_FILES['img_'.$mass_lg[$i].''], $mass_lg[$i]."_".$img_name[2]['image']); 
                    };                        
                };      


            };
```

Суть в том что, описания меняются на ура, но в то же время файлы, которые абсолютно как видно по тому же принципу должны перезаписываться работают следующим образом -> те файлы что уже существуют удаляются , а создаются новые (т.е если на сервере уже есть допустим 1 файл, а я его НЕ перезаписываю а загружаю новый для совсем иного поля, то этот 1 удаляется, и создается новый для заданного поля).Сломал голову почему именно так происходит. Подозреваю тут проверка `if` c файлом не правильная. Пробовал с `isset()`, `file_exists()` всё ни в какую + самое интересное, что опять же таки с описаниями ( то бишь текстовыми полями всё правильно)

Answer (score 1):

все таки ошибка в проверке, изменил на 
`if ($_FILES['img_'.$mass_lg[$i].'']['error'] == 0)` - заработало, но если это не совсем правильно, принимаю критику